# Azure Function v2 Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection

Tags: visual-studio, azure-function-app

When trying to publish a V2 function from Visual Studio I'm getting a publish error:

> Publish has encountered an error.
>   Publishing failed.

The messages from the Output windows are:

> Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem persists.
>   Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem persists.
>   Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: results. Line 1, position 550.

The contents of the diagnostics log are:

> 06/05/2019 11:32:37
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Publishing failed.
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.b__2()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.d__23.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.d__183.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publishing failed.<---

I have created a new HTTP function, tested it locally and the attempted to publish it.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the fix to this problem by walking through the quick start guide (again):

[Publish the Project to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio#publish-the-project-to-azure)

You need to select the option for "Run from package file (recommended)".

Comment: Thanks, looks like this works for the Azure App Service as well. I had this issue and posted a Q and A for that too. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71145588/8644294