# Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection - Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, .net-5, webdeploy

While trying to deploy a .NET 5 web app to Azure App Service from Visual Studio, I'm hit with this unhelpful error window message:

> Publish has encountered an error. Build failed. Check the Output
> window for more details.
>
> A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:
> "C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6F34.tmp"

The output window has the following error:

> Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to
> terminate the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the
> problem persists.  Learn more at:
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED.
> Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not
> closed: results. Line 1, position 550.

I tried all the steps outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?tabs=net60&pivots=development-environment-vs) in the MS docs page, and all the other related SO answers, but still can't make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trials and errors with the Publish steps, I finally figured this out.

This is what the final step needed to look like:

[image]

Essentially, checking the 'Run from package file' checkbox fixed the issue for me.

Finally, the Publish window looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED error when trying to publish to an Azure App Service. Checking the "Deploy as ZIP package" when creating the Publishing Profile from Visual Studio did the trick for me.

[image: Publishing Profiles Options]