# Web deployment task failed. Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection - Azure App Service

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy, asp.net-4.8

While trying to deploy a ASP.NET 4.8 web app (technically, an outlook add-in) to Azure App Service from Visual Studio, I'm hit with this error:
Publish has encountered an error.
Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
"C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1E71.tmp"

The output window has the following error:
Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem persists.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED.)  Epicor.Collaborate.Outlook.AddinWeb C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets  4455

Referred to a Microsoft Office Dev Center article called "Host an Office Add-in on Microsoft Azure" to deploy the add-in in Azure. Here's the address for the article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/host-an-office-add-in-on-microsoft-azure#step-3-create-a-web-app-in-azure-using-the-azure-portal

Tried to recreate this accepted solution:
[Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection - Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71145587/web-deploy-experienced-a-connection-problem-with-the-server-and-had-to-terminate)
Says, checking the 'Run from package file' checkbox fixed the issue for them.
But I'm unable to see any checkbox, neither 'Run from package file' nor 'Deploy as ZIP package'.

[Publish settings and options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulLBq.png)

Comment: Can you please share your Publish selected option and settings.

Comment: @Harshitha I have edited the question and added  Publish selected option and settings. Is that what you meant?

Comment: The option which you are looking may be available only for .net core apps..

Comment: Can you share your code repo?

Comment: What is the VisualStudio version you are using?

Comment: @Harshitha Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.8.4
Unfortunately, cannot share my code repo.

Comment: What you have configured in your framework app?

Comment: It is an outlook add-in that captured contents of a mail and shares it to a messenger, sort of like "Share to Teams" add-in.  manifest file includes configurations, specifying add-in permissions,  authentication is implemented for secure access, have set up event handlers for capturing the content of a mail, and have configured the necessary permissions to access Outlook data.

Comment: Are you able to run the app locally?

Comment: yes I am able to run it locally. I'm just unable to deploy it to azure